# Custom sort order

Tags: sorting, libreoffice-calc

I need to sort data in LibreOffice Calc using a user-defined sorting function (Small, Medium, Large, X-Large). The sort menu offers a "custom sort" option, but the sorts are all pre-defined and I do not see how to add a new one.

Disclaimer: I am completing an assignment intended for users of Microsoft Excel, but I prefer to use LibreOffice over booting up Windows.

I also need to sort cells that are formatted in a certain way, specifically cells with a red fill need to be sorted at the top of the list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "custom sort" lists are defined in the Options dialog.

You can add additional sort lists manually. Go to *Tools->Options->LibreOffice Calc->Sort Lists* and add a new list.

[image: The Sort Page in the Options dialog]

Sorting based on formatting is not yet supported in LibreOffice. There have been plans to add this functionality but nobody has worked on implementing the feature yet.

Comment: I just want to sort numbers before text, is there a way to do that?  I have a column with numbers for active rows and text for inactive rows, which I want to sort descending and have active rows from highest to lowest then inactive rows below